# scroll table view while shrinking upper UIImage

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, key-value-observing

I don't know if the title of this post is much descriptive so I'll try to explain it in more depth. I have this UserProfileViewController:

[image]

The top part is an UIImage that has those buttons as subviews and also flips from side to side. The bottom part is a container view that will display different view controller based on those buttons. The view controllers are all tableviews so what I want to achieve is that when I scroll each tableview the UIImage from the top half will shrink as the tabeview's frame will enlarge until the tableview riches the navigation bar at witch point will continue scrolling.
I've put a kvo on the contentOffset of one of the tableviews and tried to modify the size of the upper UIImage and the tableview but it's not working as expected. They don't move in sync and it's not fluent.

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"]){
        CGPoint offset = [[change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGPointValue];
        NSLog(@"Old value: %f", offset.y);

        CGRect newFrame = self.hoverView.frame;
        newFrame.size.height -= offset.y;
        self.hoverView.frame = newFrame;

        CGRect newFrame2 = self.backOfHeaderView.frame;
        newFrame2.size.height -= offset.y;
        self.backOfHeaderView.frame = newFrame2;

        CGRect newFrame3 = self.userWallViewController.activityFeedTableView.frame;
        newFrame3.origin.y -= offset.y;
        self.userWallViewController.activityFeedTableView.frame = newFrame3;
    }
}
```

Any ideas and suggestions will be very welcomed. Thanks

**UPDATE: better explanation**

So basically when you scroll with your thumb up (scroll the tableview downwards) the tableview's frame expands by going up until it's full screen and at the same time the UIImage shrinks so it should look like the tableview it's pushing the UIImage out of the screen. When you scroll with your thumb down (so you scroll the tableview upwards) the tableview's frame shrinks until it's restored at it's initial position and the UIImage will grow. It should look like the tablewview it's dragging the UIImage back on the screen. That way you can use the buttons

Comment: Hey , why you want to each at the top, why dont you fix the table frame, so that it can scroll in that values only.

Comment: When I scroll the tableview I want to have it full screen and not just half of the screen

Comment: So, at start it will be half of the screen, but you say that you have buttons to select different table view controllers, so if you expand then how you can make selection?

Comment: nobody has any suggestions? The kvo approach wasn't working because when I tried to call setContentOffset in the method above it entered a loop because this method observes contentOffset and also tries to reset it (of course, not a good way). I've also tried with notification center but the result is the same